# ¿Cómo puedo usar sql server con wampp y codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, wamp

Estoy intentando usar SQL Server con WAMP y CodeIgniter, alguien sabe por qué aparece esto o si hay una configuración especial para poder usarlo?

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

**Controlador**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Welcome_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $contenido['datos'] = $this->Welcome_model->mostrar();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $contenido);
    }
}
```

**Módelo**:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->database();
    }

    function mostrar(){
        $consulta = $this->db->select('nombre, apellido')
                            ->from('persona');

        if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0) return $consulta->result();
        else return false;
    }
}

?>
```

**Vista**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Hola Mundo</h2>

    <?php 
        echo $datos;
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Y éste es el resultado que obtengo, con un error al llamar a la función `sqlsrv_connect`:

[image: Lo que sucede]

Comment: no veo tu conexion ademas seria php y sqlserver

Comment: Para que el código no te aparezca desordenado lo debes copiar en la pregunta, seleccionar el código y presionar `Ctrl + K` de este modo se ordena solo y cumples con las normas. Si lo deseas puedes [edit](/edit) la pregunta para corregirlo. Saludos!

Comment: Tenes instalado los drivers de sql server para php?

Comment: Si, Tengo los drivers. Alguna sugerencia de un video o algo que me ayude con esto.

Comment: que configuración tienes en tu config/database.php?, ademas podrías verificar en tu phpinfo si existe o esta activado sql_srv?